# Transform function in terms of Heaviside functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am working on the red-shaded problem below however I am unsure how to use my answer from part b to answer the question. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $Y(s) = H(s) * F(s)$.

So then the response $y(t)$ can be determined by inverting $Y(s) = H(s) * F(s) = H(s) * U(s) $, where $ U(s) $ is the Laplace Transform of the Heaviside function.

Comment: But how am I supposed to understand what $U(s)$ given $H(s)$?

Comment: So, in part (b), you "back out" the system transfer function $H(s)$ using the known $F(s)$ and $Y(s)$. At that point, you know what $H(s)$ is, and that doesn't change. Now, you supply a new input $F(s) = U(s)$, and then $Y(s) = H(s) * U(s)$. Since $U(s) = \frac{1}{s}$, then $Y(s) = H(s) * \frac{1}{s} $, where $H$ is from part (b).

Comment: So that's what I thought you meant however when I tried that I didn't get the right answer. If I understand, I am supposed to take the inverse Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{H(s) * \dfrac{1}{s}\}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that should be it. Make sure you are taking the inverse transform correctly. Otherwise, I may be completely off with the question, or your answer might be formatted incorrectly, or the textbook might be wrong.